# Least squares using general matrix vector multiplication, not sparse matrices

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Is there a way to compute

```
\argmin_{x}\|Ax-b\|_2
```

based on a function that computes matrix vector products `Ax`, without explicitly storing, sparse or non-sparse, `A` in memory?

In Python, I'd use `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` for that (despite the package name, this function doesn't require sparse matrices, but allows for `LinearOperator`s.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up translating the open source code of [Scipy's lsmr](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsmr.py) to C#. Most of the already surprisingly short code there is documentation and logging, there are maybe 100 non-trivial lines, all of which have direct equivalents in BLAS.
(lsmr is an improved version of lsqr)